# When I start my PC, it shows grub rescue

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

By mistake, I deleted one disk drive to open up space.

Now, when I start my PC it shows grub rescue

```
error : unknown file system, entering rescue mode, grub rescue
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKd7y.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have touched the deleted partition/disk (?), you might be able to recover the files in it, if it's not encrypted.

You could try to use `photorec` or `testdisk` from a LIVE USB.

One important point, is how did you delete the disk drive ? The method you used will determine what you will be able to recover or not.